# how to get body holding the content of iframe in java

Tags: java, html, iframe, selenium

I am working to fetch data which is under iframe tag.I want the data under body tag.But I am not getting proper output.Here is my HTML page looks like as follows:

```
<iframe id="sharetools-iframe" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="z-index: 1000; position: relative; visibility: visible; " scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" src="some url here"></iframe>
#document
<html><head><script type="text/javascript">window.WIDGET_ID = 'sharepopup';</script>
<base href="href here">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="href here">
<script src="url here"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="url here"></script></head>
<body>
body contents are here........
..............................
</div></div></body></html>
```

I have used the following code:

```
WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
webDriver.get("url to open");
String htmlPage = webDriver.getPageSource();
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlPage.getBytes());
Document doc = tidy.parseDOM(inputStream, null);
Element element = doc.getElementById("sharetools-iframe");
```

Here I am getting element null.I have also type casted it as follows:

```
HTMLIFrameElement iframeElement = (HTMLIFrameElement) doc.getElementById("sharetools-iframe");
```

But getting iframeElement null.

I have also used jsoup parser as follows:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlPage);
org.jsoup.nodes.Element iframeElement= doc.getElementById("sharetools-iframe");
```

Here I am getting output `<iframe id="sharetools-iframe" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="z-index: 1000; position: relative; visibility: visible; " scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" src="some url here"></iframe>` as a iframeElement but not getting body content.

Please guide me how to fetch body content of iframe.

Comment: Did you check the contents of htmlPage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch to iframe and then you can interact with content.
For example to get body:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("sharetools-iframe"))).findElement(By.tagName("body"));
```